# How can I attach wall framing to my finished floor without damaging it?

Tags: drywall

I am looking for a way to join the drywall framing to the floor without drilling.

It is for a divider wall to make a reception area for clients in my business. It would have an L shape with both sides of around the same length, one of the sides would be attached to the wall, the other I was thinking of adding another L to increase its resistance. It will have 1.10m or 3 feet 7inch, of height.

But I can't drill holes in the floor.
What would you recommend to join the steel framing to the floor?

Edit 1: thanks for the answers. You guys think that would be enough to hold it? The L has 1.7x1.2m. And it should be able to hold a computer screen and other lightweight materials.
I like the caulking idea, added to the construction adhesive. I hope I don't ever need to remove it. Thanks

Comment: Unless it is a safety railing, the weight of the wall should keep it in place.  You might want something like a rubber pad under the wall to protect the floor.  The L section will keep the wall upright, and it is not you will have kids running around or mad parties to knock the wall over.

Comment: The rubber pad will also help minimize and walking it may do.

Answer (score 0):

Merely **not drilling**, construction adhesive would do.

**Not damaging** if/when the wall is removed, that **won't** do.

What *might* work better than just having it sit there would be to set it in place and apply **removable caulking** (warning, it stinks when applied, at least what I could find for that did) all around the edges (don't put it under the wall, then it can't be removed the way it's designed to work.)

When the time comes to remove it, the caulking is grabbed (a pair of pliers is handy at first) and pulled, and it releases from the surfaces it's applied to as it's pulled into a longer and thinner shape. I've used it to seal leaky windows for the winter without permanently disabling them. Some that were not opened in summer were left for as much as 5 years before removing the caulking, and it still came off without trouble or damage.

Comment: You think that would be enough to hold it? The L has 1.7x1.2m. And it should be able to hold a computer screen and other lightweight materials.